Tratar filas tipo json dentro de un CSV en un pipeline datafactory
Por medio de un servicio web se realiza la descarga de un archivo, el cual se descarga en formato CSV con varias columnas, pero estas columnas son tipo JSON.

Con ello se intenta realizar la lectura de la columna attributes, por medio de configuración de formato complex en la proyección de la siguiente manera:
(created_at as string[], attribute_name as string, attribute_value as string)
Pero el resultado del preview de los datos son valores nulos para la estructura.
Se realiza proceso de tipo PARSE/ANALIZAR y el resultado es el mismo.
El resultado final buscado es pasar esas columnas JSON a una tabla legible para un usuario de reportaría
Ejemplo de código
    source(output(
        account_id as integer,
        customer_id as string,
        type as string,
        version as short,
        cookies as string,
        attributes as (created_at as string[], attribute_name as string, attribute_value as string),
        segments as string,
        events as string,
        created_at as string,
        updated_at as string,
        first_id as string,
        anonymous as boolean
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    multiLineRow: true,
    wildcardPaths:['03_OUTPUT/ZIP/2024/09/12/data.zip/customers.csv']) ~> sCustomerCDP
source(output(
        ID as integer,
        customer_id as (type as string, value as string),
        type as string,
        version as string,
        cookies as string[],
        attributes as (created_at as string[], attribute_name as string, attribute_value as string)[]
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    inferDriftedColumnTypes: true,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    documentForm: 'singleDocument',
    unquotedColumnNames: true,
    singleQuoted: true,
    wildcardPaths:['02_STAGE/customers2.json']) ~> source1
sCustomerCDP select(mapColumn(
        account_id,
        customer_id,
        cookies,
        attributes
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1
select1 derive(arr = map(split(replace(attributes,'[',''),'],'),split(replace(replace(#item,'"',''),']',''),','))) ~> derivedColumn1
derivedColumn1 derive(newarr = unfold(slice(arr,2))) ~> derivedColumn2
select2 parse(attributes = attributes ? (created_at as string[],
        attribute_name as string,
        attribute_value as string),
    format: 'json',
    documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> parse1
select1 select(mapColumn(
        attributes
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2
select1 derive(Json_atributos = @(accountid=account_id,
        customerid=customer_id,
        caracteristicas=attributes)) ~> derivedColumn3
derivedColumn3 parse(otr = Json_atributos ? (caracteristicas as integer),
    format: 'json',
    documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> parse2

